# Jenkins build marked as failure whenever my TestNG testcase/scripts fails

Tags: selenium

Using Jenkins we are executing our TestNG XML through windows batch file.
My build is getting marked as failure when any of my test cases fails.

For example: 
- I have 5 test cases inside my TestNG XML
- First 3 test cases passes and remaining 2 test cases is getting failed

Though all my 5 test cases are successfully executed still the build is getting marked as failure.

My requirement is the build should be marked as success, Once all of my 5 test cases executes (irrespective of results).

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins is doing exactly what it should be doing: the point of executing test cases along with a build is to *fail* the build as soon as any changes break any of the regression test cases.

If this is not what you want to happen, you need to change your Jenkins setup:

- **If the tests fail because there is a real problem** - fix the application. The application might build just fine, but your tests are saying something is wrong with how it works.
- **If the tests fail because they are wrong** - fix the tests.

Failed tests do not stop the build process *completing*, but it will not complete successfully unless all tests pass.